# Openlayers TMS default image

Tags: openlayers-2, tile-map-service

In OpenLayers, when a tile is missing in a TMS layer, a semi-transparent pink rectangle shows in its place. Is there a way to load some default image, like one saying "No data for this region under this zoom" instead?

One possibility is to request the tiles through something like a PHP script or a Java servlet. If a nonexistent tile is requested, this servlet would then send the default tile.

However, I'm currently taking the tiles directly from the filesystem, so I'm looking for a solution to be done only with JS / OpenLayers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 5; // this will help in avoiding the pink tiles in the first place.
OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadError = function(){
     this.src = "images/yourImage.png";
};
```